# Conduit: Multiple Stream Consumers

Tags: haskell, nlp, conduit

I write a program which counts the frequencies of NGrams in a corpus. I already have a function that consumes a stream of tokens and produces NGrams of one single order:

```
ngram :: Monad m => Int -> Conduit t m [t]
trigrams = ngram 3
countFreq :: (Ord t, Monad m) => Consumer [t] m (Map [t] Int)
```

At the moment i just can connect one stream consumer to a stream source:

```
tokens --- trigrams --- countFreq
```

How do I connect multiple stream consumers to the same stream source?
I would like to have something like this:

```
           .--- unigrams --- countFreq
           |--- bigrams  --- countFreq
tokens ----|--- trigrams --- countFreq
           '--- ...      --- countFreq
```

A plus would be to run each consumer in parallel

**EDIT:**
Thanks to Petr I came up with this solution

```
spawnMultiple orders = do
    chan <- atomically newBroadcastTMChan

    results <- forM orders $ \_ -> newEmptyMVar
    threads <- forM (zip results orders) $
                        forkIO . uncurry (sink chan)

    forkIO . runResourceT $ sourceFile "test.txt"
                         $$ javascriptTokenizer
                         =$ sinkTMChan chan

    forM results readMVar

    where
        sink chan result n = do
            chan' <- atomically $ dupTMChan chan
            freqs <- runResourceT $ sourceTMChan chan'
                                 $$ ngram n
                                 =$ frequencies
            putMVar result freqs
```

Comment: You want that when `tokens` yields a value, all your `...grams` receive it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm assuming you want all your sinks to receive all values.

I'd suggest:

1. Use [`newBroadcastTMChan`](http://code.haskell.org/~wren/stm-chans/dist/doc/html/stm-chans/Control-Concurrent-STM-TMChan.html#v:newBroadcastTMChan) to create a new channel `Control.Concurrent.STM.TMChan` (stm-chans).
2. Use this channel to build a sink using [`sinkTBMChan`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/stm-conduit/0.2.4.1/doc/html/Data-Conduit-TMChan.html#v:sinkTBMChan) from `Data.Conduit.TMChan` (stm-conduit) for your main producer.
3. For each client use `dupTMChan` to create its own copy for reading. Start a new thread that will read this copy using `sourceTBMChan`.
4. Collect results from your threads.
5. Be sure your clients can read the data as fast as they're produced, otherwise you can get heap overflow.

(I haven't tried it, let us know how it works.)

---

**Update:** One way how you could collect the results is to create a [`MVar`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Concurrent-MVar.html#t:MVar) for each consumer thread. Each of them would `putMVar` its result after it's finished. And your main thread would `takeMVar` on all these `MVar`s, thus waiting for every thread to finish. For example if `vars` is a list of your `MVar`s, the main thread would issue `mapM takeMVar vars` to collect all the results.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, how do i collect the results if i spawn the threads with forkIO?

Comment: @SvenK I updated the answer with an idea how to collect the results.

Comment: Why does TMChan have a broadcast version, and TBMChan doesn't, where can I find a `newBroadcastTBMChan`?